# How to get data from Service in IntentService?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

In my app I have a Service (MainService) that runs in background and handles some data like images, messages, etc.

I need to show additional data (sender's avatar for example) from this service in my GCM notifications.

I've implemented GCM like this:

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmNotificationService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**GcmNotificationService.java:**

```
public class GcmNotificationService extends IntentService{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        //Need to retreive data from MainService
        //Tried to bind to MainService here
        ...
        //Send notification
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't simply bind to my MainService in *onHandleIntent* because it's thread closes earlier than I receive *onServiceConnected*.

I also tried to extend *IntentService* in MainService, but it's bad idea.

What should I do to achieve this functionality?

Comment: so use: public class GcmNotificationService extends **Service** { ... and now `bindService` will work

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "MainService handles some data"? Does it keep a websocket connection to a server and receives/sends data or something like that? In that case, where does it store the data received?

Comment: @Piovezan, MainService keeps socket.io connection with the server. It stores most of the data in memory, but uses UIL for caching images on sdcard. It means that I need at least access user profile to retrieve image URI.

Comment: @pskink, thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: Why do you have to bind to MainService to retrieve user data? Can't you keep the data globally accessible in the application by means of a Singleton or something so the service is able to access the data it needs?

Comment: @pskink, it worked, thanks a lot!